# Where are buffer level variables stored in Vim? And how to get their RAM / storage usage?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, buffers, viminfo

Where does Vim store `b:` buffer level variables / dictionaries? RAM or some kind of file on a disk?

If it stores it in RAM, how to get an estimate of RAM / storage used by a particular variable / dictionary?

Asking for both Vim & Neovim.

Comment: it stores on RAM

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim, if you look at the source code for [`buflist_new()`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f6a8d420a8d2924737f713de046947dcb487550c/src/buffer.c#L1963) which adds a filename to the buffer list you'll find the part [where the `b:` dictionary is initialized](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f6a8d420a8d2924737f713de046947dcb487550c/src/buffer.c#L2065-L2073)

```
// init b: variables
buf->b_vars = dict_alloc();
if (buf->b_vars == NULL)
{
    vim_free(ffname);
    vim_free(buf);
    return NULL;
}
init_var_dict(buf->b_vars, &buf->b_bufvar, VAR_SCOPE);
```

And in [`dict.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f6a8d420a8d2924737f713de046947dcb487550c/src/dict.c#L28-L49) you'll see that this dictionary is allocated in RAM, you'll also see that there is no code to store these dictionaries on disk.

Now to determine the size of a variable you'll need to do as you'd usually do with any other C program, I don't believe there is a particular interface to let the use to that easily from Vim itself.

To get an idea of how the data is stored in a dictionary you can see that in the signature of [`dict_add(dict_T *d, dictitem_T *item)`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f6a8d420a8d2924737f713de046947dcb487550c/src/dict.c#L352-L355) that the dictionary items are typed `dictitem_T`, have a look at [`structs.h`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f6a8d420a8d2924737f713de046947dcb487550c/src/structs.h#L1508-L1519) to see:

```
/*
 * Structure to hold an item of a Dictionary.
 * Also used for a variable.
 * The key is copied into "di_key" to avoid an extra alloc/free for it.
 */
struct dictitem_S
{
typval_T    di_tv;      // type and value of the variable
char_u  di_flags;   // DI_FLAGS_ flags (only used for variable)
char_u  di_key[1];  // key (actually longer!)
};
typedef struct dictitem_S dictitem_T;
```

which leads us to the [`typval_T` definition](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f6a8d420a8d2924737f713de046947dcb487550c/src/structs.h#L1409-L1432):

```
/*
 * Structure to hold an internal variable without a name.
 */
typedef struct
{
vartype_T   v_type;
char    v_lock;     // see below: VAR_LOCKED, VAR_FIXED
union
{
    varnumber_T v_number;   // number value
#ifdef FEAT_FLOAT
    float_T     v_float;    // floating number value
#endif
    char_u      *v_string;  // string value (can be NULL!)
    list_T      *v_list;    // list value (can be NULL!)
    dict_T      *v_dict;    // dict value (can be NULL!)
    partial_T   *v_partial; // closure: function with args
#ifdef FEAT_JOB_CHANNEL
    job_T       *v_job;     // job value (can be NULL!)
    channel_T   *v_channel; // channel value (can be NULL!)
#endif
    blob_T      *v_blob;    // blob value (can be NULL!)
}       vval;
} typval_T;
```

And from there you'll find out that these variables are simple types, for example the `char_u` type used for the string is defined [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f6a8d420a8d2924737f713de046947dcb487550c/src/vim.h#L320-L324) for a string:

```
/*
 * Shorthand for unsigned variables. Many systems, but not all, have u_char
 * already defined, so we use char_u to avoid trouble.
 */
typedef unsigned char   char_u;
```

As for neovim I didn't check but I think they do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given by @statox, I did some testing & found out the RAM used by dictionary variables in (Neo)Vim. I don't have any experience with C language, so I did testing in a following way.

### Process

1. I created 100 dummy .txt files with random data around a few KB. Totaling 1.5 MB size. With bash script.
2. I added below code in my .vimrc. This opens those 100 random files when Vim starts & defines the below long dictionary with **640 properties** & lots of nestings to `b:BUG` variable (sorry for irrelevant name).
3. I checked the RAM usage of Vim in bashtop, with & without defining those 100 dictionaries. Both scenarios multiple times to get accurate RAM usage.

### Random file creation code (Bash)

```
for n in {0..100}; do
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=$( printf %01d "$n" ).txt bs=1 count=$(( RANDOM + 1024 ))
done
```

(Renamed)

### Vimrc code

```
"autocmd BufEnter * call Add_BUG()

function! Add_BUG()
if !exists('b:BUG')
let l:bnum = bufnr()
let b:bnum = l:bnum
let b:BUG = {'aaa': l:bnum, 'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{'alpha':'the-alpha-man', 'beta':'the-beta-man', 'gamma':'the-gamma-man', 23:23, 'rada':{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
endif
endfunction

let g:BUGINT = 0

while g:BUGINT < 100
tabnew
execute 'edit ' . g:BUGINT . '.txt'
let g:BUGINT = g:BUGINT + 1
endwhile
```

### Result

**With 100 variables:** 33 MB RAM.

**Without 100 variables:** 25.5 MB RAM.

**Total RAM used by 100 variables:** 7.5 MB.

**RAM used per variable:** ~75 KB.

#### Conclusion

I needed this info (in my statusline Vim plugin) to decide whether to re-calculate info  on buffer enter or store it in a variable. There is a lot of data I need to store.

Since the RAM usage is very very low, it's a good idea to store it rather than re-calculate it.